Derailleur HANGER to replace an old Sunrace with its own hanger
My old folding bike does not have a hanger in the frame for the derailleur.
However, it has a SunRace M2T derailleur that includes its own  hanger.
But I need to replace it, as I replaced the 5-speed freewheel with a 6-speed one, increasing the largest cog from 28T to 34T as well (specifically a freewheel 14-34T Shimano MegaRange F-TZ30-CP), and as expected, the old derailleur is not working smoothly after so big of a change.
So, I need to replace the rear derailleur with a "better" unit and all of them require a HANGER in the frame.

What type of hanger do I need? Also, steel or aluminum?

Actually, sunrace make one. And it's cheap. I'll iook for the part no.

Aluminium. You want the hanger to sacrifice itself and protect the frame in the event of a crash or a bash. To that end, hangers are made with a relatively soft grade of aluminium.

@WarrenBurton I don't think that's a concern for this type of hanger....and I doubt an alu version is madc

Worth noting all of Sunrace's M2T 6 speed derailleurs are max 28T compatible. So you will likely need to opt for a different brand/model

28T is frequent max cog. However many derailleurs can reach more teeth but you need to test or find unofficial information. This Sunrace M2T would work perfectly with 32T

Sunrace SP550
works with all standard derailleurs. Very cheap to buy.
Other brands possibly (or possibly not) available.

